# Determining Internet Explorer Cookie Settings Through the Windows Registry

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, registry

Is there a way to determine Internet Explorer Cookie Settings (that is, whether cookies are accepted or not) through the Windows Registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569) is a nice MS knowledge base article about how IE's security zones are managed in the registry.

It looks like this is the relevant part:

```
The following four registry entries take only effect if the following keys are present:
{AEBA21FA-782A-4A90-978D-B72164C80120} First Party Cookie 
{A8A88C49-5EB2-4990-A1A2-0876022C854F} Third Party Cookie 

Registry entries
1A02 Allow persistent cookies that are stored on your computer 
1A03 Allow per-session cookies (not stored) 
1A05 Allow 3rd party persistent cookies 
1A06 Allow 3rd party session cookies 

These registry entries are located in the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\<ZoneNumber>
```

and I'll add (from the same article) that these are the default zone numbers (although a user can customize these):

```
   0        My Computer
   1        Local Intranet Zone
   2        Trusted sites Zone
   3        Internet Zone
   4        Restricted Sites Zone
```