# Find Registry Key for: Override automatic cookie handling

Tags: windows-7, key, registry

I want to set the IE7 privacy settings via the registry and I am not having any luck 
finding what keys need to be set. I am trying to do the following:

Override automatic cookie handling;
Allow first party cookies;
Block third party cookies;
Always Allow session cookies;

Anyone know what keys are to be set and what the settings would be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To Override automatic cookie handling use:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\PrivacyAdvanced
```

Answer (score 1):

Was i need to change that myself, hope this will help other guys:
Combining and adding some:

Read that page for more detailed info : [M$- Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=182569)

also other answer for Internet zones [StackOverflow- Answer about zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427789/determining-internet-explorer-cookie-settings-through-the-windows-registry)

below working script for:
"Override automatic cookie handling"

- 1st party Cookies: Accept
- 3rd party Cookies: Blocked
- Always allow session cookies

just save it as file with *.reg extension

```js
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
    "PrivacyAdvanced"=dword:00000001
    
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3]
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3]
    "{AEBA21FA-782A-4A90-978D-B72164C80120}"=hex:1a,37,61,59,23,52,35,0c,7a,5f,20,\
    17,2f,1e,1a,19,0e,2b,01,73,13,37,13,12,14,1a,15,2a,4e,2c,08,0d,20,1b,28,18,\
    36,32
    "{A8A88C49-5EB2-4990-A1A2-0876022C854F}"=hex:1a,37,61,59,23,52,35,0c,7a,5f,20,\
    17,2f,1e,1a,19,0e,2b,01,73,13,37,13,12,14,1a,15,39,4e,2c,08,0d,20,1b,28,18,\
    36,32
```

Good Luck