# How can I use ASP.NET to check if cookies are enabled without having a web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cookies, client-server

I am working on a desktop application that automates numerous websites and processes the returned data.  This application will be run on a server and the user will connect with remote desktop.  The automation breaks when the server doesn't have cookies enabled, and instead of having the application stop working, I would like to check the server settings and tell the user why it isn't working.

To do this, I decided to create an ASP.NET Web Service.  I figured that the web service could store the cookie and then try to access the data.  If the data is found, cookies are enabled and everything is good to go.

I have read numerous tutorials like: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/05/c-and-cookies/ that explain how to store and access cookies through ASP.NET.  All of these however use a website.  The user clicks a button to generate a request and the web service can then send a response.  I do not know how to make the process work without having a website, and I do not wish to automate a site of my own hosting as well.  I feel like I should be able to run a method on my webservice and it should work.

Does anyone know how this would be done? I'd like a webservice that can handle request and response so I can create, store, and access cookies.  I thank you for any help that you may offer.

Nathan Tornquist

EDIT:

I am working on an database driven application.  Some of the pieces are automated web sites, where the user puts in some data and then the program opens up a webBrowser control, fills in the forms, and then formats the resulting data. I would like to test if cookies are enabled based on the users security privileges so that I can disable automation and allow the user to fill in the data on their own if required. Most of the websites require cookies to log in.

This will be running on various versions of Windows Server.  By default I think the webBrowser control has the same security settings as Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is this desktop application using the WebBrowser control to automate the sites? You're saying the application breaks if the WebBrowser control doesn't have cookies enabled? Why not enable them?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're doing.  Cookies are a function of the client (usually the browser) not the server.  If you are writing code that takes the place of the browser, then it is up to you to make sure your code is handling cookies.

Comment: I am just one of many developers.  Cookies should be enabled, but depending on the company, the people I work with may or may not be the network managers.  By testing to see if cookies are enabled, I not only keep the automation from endlessly breaking, but I allow the user to see what is wrong so it can be fixed.  IE, I don't have the power to enable them.  Instead of getting a bug report every time it breaks, I'd like it to be fixed by the network administrator.

Comment: Are all users using the same browser?  Which one?

Comment: I believe that it's all Internet Explorer based.  The cookie privileges are set by the server manager though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify those keys on registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones

Under those keys, you may see some keys like 0, 1, 2, 3 ... Each one is a Zone configuration.

Search for those entries in each Zone:

1A02
1A03
1A05
1A06

So you have to verify if those entries values are equals to 0.

See those links:

[ms kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569)
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2427789/830523)

Comment: I am writing a Windows Forms application that runs on Windows Server.  The application takes data and then automates a webBrowser control.  The cookie issue is on the server that the application lives on.

Comment: Ok. The automation proccess must be visible? You 'must' use the WebBrowser control? Or you just need to do a web request and process the response?

Comment: @nathan-tornquist: Yes. You can do your own requests.

Comment: That would perfectly for a specific user, but if the cookie control is done with Group Policy, which it mainly is for my clients, it will still break.  That idea is certainly a step in the right direction though.  Thank you.

Comment: @nathan-tornquist: So, can you detect the error? If you can do, you can show an error message explaining the problem.

Comment: The sites that I am automating don't give the user an error message when it doesn't work.  It just doesn't respond to anything.  I actually didn't know it was a cookie problem until I tried hotmail.com and got the list of errors. I can't just test hotmail.com because that would be blocked on most of the computers my software would run on, and ultimately it would take too long to load. -- I actually got the web service working the way that I wanted only to learn that it doesn't test the right pieces.  Without having a web page the application is tested, not the user's internet settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
request.Method =  "Head";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var usesCookies = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Headers["Set-Cookie"]);
```

Comment: That code tells me if the website uses cookies, but does not tell me if cookies are enabled or not.