# Where does Request and Response in ASP.NET come from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I feel like this is a rather simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I understand how to create a webRequest with HttpWebRequest, send it to the server, and handle the response.

In Microsoft's ASP.NET examples like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Get cookie from the current request.
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("DateCookieExample");

    // Check if cookie exists in the current request.
    if (cookie == null)
    {
        sb.Append("Cookie was not received from the client. ");
        sb.Append("Creating cookie to add to the response. <br/>");
        // Create cookie.
        cookie = new HttpCookie("DateCookieExample");
        // Set value of cookie to current date time.
        cookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        // Set cookie to expire in 10 minutes.
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10d);
        // Insert the cookie in the current HttpResponse.
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append("Cookie retrieved from client. <br/>");
        sb.Append("Cookie Name: " + cookie.Name + "<br/>");
        sb.Append("Cookie Value: " + cookie.Value + "<br/>");
        sb.Append("Cookie Expiration Date: " + 
            cookie.Expires.ToString() + "<br/>");
    }
    Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

(From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx)

Request and Response are already declared and just exist.

I am developing a web service instead of a full website.  Is this why I do not see Request and Response already defined?

I do not understand why I am having so much trouble with this.  I asked a similar question here: [How can I use ASP.NET to check if cookies are enabled without having a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599195/how-can-i-use-asp-net-to-check-if-cookies-are-enabled-without-having-a-web-page) so either I am missing something completely obvious, or the problem I am trying to solve is very nonstandard.

I thank you for any help.

EDIT:

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public bool CookiesEnabledOnClient()
    {
        bool retVal = true;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.dealerbuilt.com");
        request.Method = "Head";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        HttpCookie Httpcookie = new HttpCookie("CookieAccess", "true");

        response.Cookies.Add(Httpcookie);      
        //If statement checking if cookie exists.

        return retVal;
    }
```

But Cookies.Add will not accept the Httpcookie and when I use a normal cookie it isn't added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, in ASP.Net the Page_Load() method (and any other method on a web page) is a member of a class, and this class inherits from [another class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx).  The [properties list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_properties.aspx) of that base class includes both [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request.aspx) and [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.response.aspx).

As for the latter part of your question, look for the [`Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.context.aspx#Y500) variable. It is already defined for your web service in a manner similar to how Request and Response are available in a web page, and it will give you access to those properties, including any cookies in the request.

Comment: So because I'm not using an event driven method, I don't inherit the response or request?

Comment: @Nathan: No, its because you are not in a class derived from Page. I think Joel confused the matter by mentioning Page_Load. Forget that and just remember that your web page inherits from System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: I will not be using a web page though.  I am just writing a web service.  With that, is there a special protocol I need to follow to make my web requests and such act the same as they would with a page?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code above is in a class inheriting from [System.Web.UI.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx). This has the Request and Response objects on this base class and thus they are available in your derived class.

A standard web service will inherit from [System.Web.Services.WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx). This does not have the Request and Response declared on it. However, it does have a "Context" Property which is an [HTTPContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) object which defines properties for Response and Request.

I'm not sure what differences there might be on these objects in a service compared to a standard web page but I guess the core things are the same. And I have no idea why they didn't define them both on the WebService class itself...

Comment: That's what I needed.  Thanks to you as well.

Comment: No prob. I hadn't actually noticed Joel had updated his answer to mention a bit about services when I posted mine but glad you appreciated it anyway. :)